# What does this Gaussian window size equation mean?

Tags: computer-vision

[Gaussian Window size W Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojuU.png)

I came across this from a paper in Computer Vision. What exactly is an average operator? What I understood at the very least from this equation is that the loci r1 and r2 are from the images f and g's pixels which are being aligned. Also, the min dictates that it searches for the minimum differences of r1 and r2.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur . $W$ is $1/\sigma$ or $1/\sigma^2$ of wikipedia's article